# How to achieve split look of the Android Honeycomb Gmail app?

Tags: android, listview, layout, gmail, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have searched quite extensively throught stackoverflow but unfortunately found no conclusive answer to my question.

I simply wish to achieve the look of the view positioning similar to the Gmail app on Honeycomb tablets (check the picture)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC75p.jpg

In my case there would be a list of employees on the left side and, after clicking on one of them, data about them would appear on the right side of the screen as in the Gmail app. Both views would preferably be scrollable.

From which angle should I be approaching this?

UPDATE: After googling the issue for a bit I think Fragments may be the key. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, fragments are the key.

If you create a layout containing two LinearLayouts in the horizontal alignment, you can fill these with two seperate `Fragments`, creating the look you're looking for.

For an example check [this example from the SDK](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html).
It also contains a list which opens an image in the other fragment when you select an item in the list. Of course you can also use this to show an employee as you want.

Comment: Yes, I am sure this is what I was looking for then. Also, thanks for the excellent SDK example, I will check it out further :).